# Firebase querying WHERE

Tags: ios, objective-c, filter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm researching what backend to use for my next project. Firebase is at the forefront right now.

However, when querying with Firebase, it seems you can't do traditional SQL queries, because its a JSON database? Such as WHERE foo... Seems to be limited to EQUALS.

If I wanted to do something like WHERE foo less than or more than, don't tell I have to just grab ALL the data and filter it locally?

Or is it because JSON is much lighter than an SQL database, its far more workable to just fetch big chunks of data paginated and then filter locally?

Comment: There are other options for querying data - can you provide a snippet of your Firebase structure (as text please) and a use case? It would be easier to directly address the issue with those data points.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of **Where clause** , there is several methods that you can use to filter firebase data...

You check the [latest Doc.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/retrieve-data#filtering_data), section Filter data

**Filtering data**

*To filter data, you can combine any of the limit or range methods with an order-by method when constructing a query.*

```
Method               |  Usage
------------------------------------------------------------------
queryLimitedToFirst     Sets the maximum number of items to return from the beginning of the ordered list of results.
queryLimitedToLast      Sets the maximum number of items to return from the end of the ordered list of results.
queryStartingAtValue    Return items greater than or equal to the specified key, value, or priority, depending on the order-by method chosen.
queryEndingAtValue      Return items less than or equal to the specified key, value, or priority, depending on the order-by method chosen.
queryEqualToValue       Return items equal to the specified key, value, or priority, depending on the order-by method chosen.
```

> Unlike the order-by methods, you can combine multiple limit or range functions. For example, you can combine the queryStartingAtValue and queryEndingAtValue methods to limit the results to a specified range of values.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is true that in Firebase you won't find typical SQL queries like simply doing `where something > somevalue`, however they do provide option similar to basic where clauses of sql.

For example

if we have a query like `where height > 3`

We do it in firebase like

```
 FQuery *queryRef = [[ref queryOrderedByChild:@"height"] queryStartingAtValue:@3];
```

Legacy docs explain that in great detail
https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html